# Blinking blue power button on a HP tower

Tags: data-recovery, desktop-computer

My computer was on when the power went out and now has a flashing blue power button. We tried removing ram to reset then the battery then dusting it out and lastly removing all components and plugging into a different outlet.

There are 4 constant blinks in a sequence! All of my work files are on there and I don't have them backed up! (I know, I know! ) I have learned my lesson and will promise to back them up immediately if this works again! I just never knew how and never took the time to do it!

Comment: I feel your pain.  But before we can help you, can you specify the model of the computer?

Comment: My clairvoyant powers predict an [HP Pavilion or Presario](http://h30499.www3.hp.com./t5/Notebook-PCs-Pavilions-Presario/blue-light-blinks-four-times-never-boots/td-p/533337).  Do you think we'll receive more response from the questioner here than was received in that case?  (-:

Answer (score 0):

Your data is on the computers harddisk, which means you have two goals:

1. Make a safe backup of your data.
2. Figure out how to get your tower working again.

Do step 1 first. Then you have a backup in case anything goes wrong later on.

Making a backup is trivial. Open the tower. Remove the harddrive (which usually is SATA) and either connect it to another tower as an additional drive or place it in an external disk case. If it is a 3½ inch  drive make sure that you get one for that format and with its own power supply.

After you have your backup start diagnosing the computer. First step it try see what happens if you power up in a minimal configuration. That is no memory, no add in cards, no drives, no floppies, no CDROMs, ... just PSU, motherboard, CPU and CPU-fan.  It should power up and give off beep codes. (probably the beep code for missing memory).

If that does not work then you have a broken PSU, failed CPU or failed motherboard.

Add the RAM and test again. If it fails add it one DIMM at a time.
Repeat with the graphics card etc etc. Up to the point where you identify the problem.